# std::string vs string

Tags: c++, string, namespaces, std

I'm using in my code many namespaces including the std one , so when I want to declare a string variable in my code should I precise std::string or I can just put string :

```
#include <string.h> 

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace xerces;

int main()
{
    /*! should I declare my str like this */
    std::string str;
    /*! or I can declare it like this */
    string str1;
    cout << str << str1 <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is what `using` is for :)

Comment: `#include <string.h>` doesn't bring you `std::string` declaration

Comment: [Why is 'using namespace std;' considered a bad practice in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1453605/140719)

Comment: @Tadeusz: and it certainly doesn't bring you namespace `xerces`! This code doesn't compile, the questioner has left out the real includes.

Comment: As a terminally lazy vim user, I have `imap <F9> std::` in my vimrc. Hit F9: get the `std::` for 1 key press.

Comment: it's just a little part of the code that I'm using , I just focused on the string thing , I mean I'm even using other namespaces that I'd created and some classes hold same name as classes in those given namespace so I was wondering should I precise everytime the namespace before the called class or only just when I have similar name classes in these different namespaces ??

Comment: @Glolita: StackOverflow isn't going to give you a definitive "yes/no" answer to a question that's a matter of style.

Comment: @juergend: No. That is how `using` is abused.

Comment: @Glolita the only definitive rule is: don't ever put `using namespace x;` into a header file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you have `using namespace std;`, the name `string` means the same as `std::string`[*]. It's therefore a question of style which you prefer (and if you prefer `std::string` then you can leave out `using namespace std;`).

There are some name clashes between `std::` and `boost::`, in particular for things that were trialled in Boost prior to standardization. So for example if you include the appropriate headers then both `std::shared_ptr` and `boost::shared_ptr` exist. They may or may not refer to the same type, I haven't checked whether Boost tries to detect the standard type before defining its own.

So it's not necessarily a good idea to use both `std` and `boost` namespaces at the same time. You can use individual names with `using std::string;`, instead of the whole namespace.

[*] if `std::string` is defined, which it isn't, since you didn't include `<string>`.

Comment: ok I already got that, but what if I needed in my code two classes from two different namespaces that have the same name ( but of course not the same implementation, let's say my code is a switching class or something like that) so I need to precise the namespace name before my called class , but once I did that shouldn't I keep doing it even with the classes that doesn't have a similar name in the other used namespaces ???

Comment: @Glolita: it's entirely up to you (or your boss, if your boss wrote your style guide). Just because some names are ambiguous, and therefore require a namespace prefix, doesn't mean that you have to write a namespace prefix on every name. If you want to write `string`, and it doesn't clash with any other definition of `string`, then first do either `using namespace std;` or `using std::string;`. I prefer `using std::string;`, because I don't like to import a great long list of names, some of which I've never heard of, and that might change in a future compiler release.

Answer (score 5):

You can just write `string`. But what if `boost` or `xerces` also have a symbol `string`? I would advise against using these `using` directives. It is not only `string` that could clash. You are essentially pulling a whole lot of symbols into the global namespace. If you really want to avoid typing `std::` then you can use a typedef:

```
typedef std::string MyStr;
```

Comment: Or worse: what if you type `strong`, meaning to type `std::string` and there's a `boost::strong`?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes good point. Or if you have a templated `set` function, as in a question I saw recently.

Answer (score 4):

You can put just `string` if you use `using namespace std;`.

Adding `using namespace std;` may not be the best idea in all cases, because it can lead to conflicts between namespaces in some cases (though unlikey for `string`).

Answer (score 3):

Usually it is not needed to specify `std::string` if you have declared `using namespace std;` **BUT** as a general case, if there are multiple namespaces which contain different classes with the same name, then you will have to specify the namespace next to the type (`namespace::type`) regardless of the existence of the `using` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the namespace `std` so you do not NEED to prepend `string` with `std::` but you CAN if you want.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to code is not to use any relevant namespace in headers, in order to prevent exposing the namespaces outer when #include. But in compiled source, you can do whatever you want, even using the std namespace and call std::string. Sometimes it's even needed (if you include two namespaces that define the same string class).